# Progress bar and webview issue

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, progress-bar

When I replace `Relative Layout` with `Linear Layout` my **webview** takes whole screen including toolbar but **progress bar** works fine **AND** when I use `Linear Layout` my **web view** starts below toolbar but it doesn't show **progress bar**.

My webview should start below toolbar with a progress bar in center.
Help me fix this

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.MyWebView">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/wbtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Comment: Keep relative layout and add this  `android:layout_below="@id/appbar"` in webview. and this id should belong to AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Replace your **`LinearLayout`** with **`RelativeLayout`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MenuButtonActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/wbtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```